# How to detect if a MySql query was successful or not and output a message?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am making a library management system using C#. For example I have a form to add a book. Once you input all the details and run the query to add books to the database, I wish to know how you can detect if the query was successful or not and output a message.

Form Code:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string isbn = txtISBN.Text;
        string title = txtbkTitle.Text;
        string author = txtbkAuthor.Text;
        string publisher = txtbkPublisher.Text;
        string imgPath = txtimgPath.Text;
        string catalog = txtCatalog.Text;


        book bc = new book(isbn, title, author, publisher, imgPath, catalog);
        utility = new DBUtlitiesBook();

        utility.Insert(bc);
    }
```

This code takes all the details of user entries, store them in variables and send them to the a method which have the insert query.

This is the method:

```
public override void Insert(object ob)
    {

        book bk = (book)ob;
        string isbn = bk.Isbn;
        string title = bk.Title;
        string author = bk.Author;
        string publisher = bk.Publisher;
        string localPath = bk.Imgpath;
        string catalogid = bk.CatalogID;



        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conn);
        MySqlCommand cmd;


        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BOOK(ISBN, title, author, publisher,imgPath, catalogID) VALUES ('" + isbn + "','" + title + "','" + author + "','" + publisher + "','" + localPath + "','" + catalogid + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();

            }
        }
    }
```

(This method overrides another method which is in the parent class)

Can you help me solve my problem?

Thanks

Comment: You should escape the input in order to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: Your query was successful if you don't catch any exception in my opinion.

Comment: How is it not enough for you to generate the error in the catch?

Comment: The way I understand MySQL, an insert returns either true or false.  Just check for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use below menioned code

```
try
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BOOK(ISBN, title, author, publisher,imgPath, catalogID) VALUES ('" + isbn + "','" + title + "','" + author + "','" + publisher + "','" + localPath + "','" + catalogid + "')";
            int a= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             if(a>0)
               //updated.
             else
              //Not updated.
        }
catch (Exception)
        {
           //Not updated.
        }
```

Comment: and where exactly I need to place that in the method?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, for `INSERT` statement, [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the count of the row affected. That's why you can check it like;

```
int rowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

if(rowCount == 1) //or you can use > 0
{
   //Successful
}
else
{
  //Unsuccessfull
}
```

By the way please use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand`.

```
using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conn))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BOOK(ISBN, title, author, publisher,imgPath, catalogID) VALUES (@isbn, @title, @author, @publisher, @path, @id)";
    ...
    //Add your parameter values one by one.
    connection.Open();
    int rowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if(rowCount == 1) //or you can use > 0
    {
       //Successful
    }
    else
    {
      //Unsuccessfull
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteNonQuery` retuns the an int indicating the number of rows affected. So, it will return zero if nothing was done. You can have a boolean condition on its return value and return a message or the value itself. You will have to probably modify the parent class so that re can have a return value.

Answer (score 0):

Errors are indicated by Exceptions that are thrown when using the MySql connector library. You should not rethrow the Exception if you want to handle the failure.

You also don't want to catch **all** exceptions and handle them at once. Instead, just catch just the MySqlException. I'm not sure in which namespace the class lives, you'll have to locate this by yourself.

```
catch (MySqlException exception)
{
    // handle the error, show some message
}
```