# Check if table creation was successful

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a Winforms app that has to migrate data from SQL to MySQL. Part of the functionality requires preparing the target database by adding the required tables (and dropping existing tables if necessary).

I'm looking for the most efficient way to determine if the table was created successfully. [This question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061615/how-to-detect-if-a-mysql-query-was-successful-or-not-and-output-a-message) suggested that executing the query would return an integer value greater than 0 if it was successful. Ideally, I'd like to execute the command and use a return value rather than running another query. Is this possible?

My current code:

```
MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
string sql = @" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS    `sf_root_items`;
                CREATE TABLE            `sf_root_items` (
                                        `ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                                        `LoweredName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                                        `MenuName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                                        `Title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                                        `Description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                                        `PageType` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                                        `ExternalUrl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                                        PRIMARY KEY(`ID`)
                                        )";
MySqlCommand cmd;
try
{
    if (myConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        myConnection.Close();
        myConnection.Open();
    }
    cmd = myConnection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    int output = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // a value greater than 0 means execution was successful
    if (output > 0)
    {
        DBPrepDone = "Table created";
    }
    else
    {
        DBPrepDone = "There was an error";
    }

    myConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    DBPrepDone = ex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: But your code already does check the output - whats the question

Comment: I was looking for some sort of return value from executing the drop & create statement but yes, you're right,  it does work in testing. Is this overkill? Or would the exception/error would be thrown in the `catch` since I'm using `try` & `catch`

Comment: a few comments.. your connection would only be closed if you successfully got to the end of your code, personally, Id make a nonquery method which connects, tries, determins success/fail, and closes so you can repeatedly call it and use true/false everywhere else

Comment: You should use exception handling because the exception would tell you what went wrong, not just that sg went wrong. Also, your are executing 2 sql commands. I'm not really sure what the return value is if only one of the 2 statements failed.

Comment: Thanks @BugFinder, the code you see is in a "PrepDB" method that is called on a click event & returns the `DBPrepDone` string. Do you have an example of what you're suggesting?

Comment: @Shadow isn't the `try`..`catch` method that I'm using sufficient? To avoid pasting too much code, I omitted that the above is a method that returns the success message or the SQL Exception

Comment: @Daniel what part dont you understand?

Comment: @BugFinder I'm using is a method that is supposed to do what you're suggesting - unless I'm wrong, in which case, can you steer me in the correct direction?

Comment: fwiw, the `myConnection.Close();` line should be in the `finally` block instead of at the end of the `try` block (this echoes what BugFinder is saying). Also, you should **NOT** try to re-use the same connection object throughout the application, because it interferes with the connection pooling ADO.Net is _already doing for you_. The result is reusing the connection actually makes things _slower_. Instead, most queries should have their own short-lived connection object. But to address the question: if you don't get an exception, you can trust the SQL statement executed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a description of ExecuteNonQuery return values from Microsoft site

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> Although the ExecuteNonQuery returns no rows, any output parameters or
>   return values mapped to parameters are populated with data. For
>   UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number
>   of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table
>   being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of
>   rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of
>   rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

To make your query work you should add check of existing your table, for example

```
string sql = @" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS    `sf_root_items`;
    CREATE TABLE            `sf_root_items` (
                            `ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                            `LoweredName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                            `MenuName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                            `Title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                            `Description` text,
                            `PageType` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                            `ExternalUrl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                            PRIMARY KEY(`ID`)
                            )";
string sql_check = @" SELECT count(*)
                    FROM information_schema.TABLES
                    WHERE (TABLE_NAME = 'sf_root_items')
                    AND (TABLE_SCHEMA = '" + WP_db.Text +"')";

MySqlCommand cmd;
try
{
    if (myConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        myConnection.Close();
        myConnection.Open();
    }
    cmd = myConnection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //call check if table was created
    cmd = myConnection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = sql_check;
    var test = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    int output;
    int.TryParse(test.ToString(), out output);

    // a value greater than 0 means execution was successful
    if (output > 0)
    {
        DBPrepDone = "Table 'sf_root_items' has been created";
    }
    else
    {
        DBPrepDone = "There was an error";
    }

    myConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    DBPrepDone = ex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: There's a slight syntax error with your code but otherwise it worked perfectly! Thank you! Do you mind if I update it?

Comment: This is a massive overkill for confirming the table creation.

Comment: Thanks @MikkaRin please review and approve to help others

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the proposed/accepted solution by @MikkaRin is that you have to know of the exact structure of your database beforehand, what objects are supposed to be created etc. You have to write a validation query yourself. Needless to say, the script might create a table just fine, but it would fail to create an index for that query. I have learned this the hard way..

Initially I had the same problem as the author. The script opens up the SQL file and runs migrations in it:

```
void RunMigrations(IDbConnection connection, string fileName)
{

    var file = new FileInfo(fileName);
    string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = script;

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

No exceptions are thrown in case of erros.

My proposed solution is to split the scripts into separate sub-scripts and execute them separately. Exceptions are throws just fine:

```cs
void RunMigrations(IDbConnection connection, string fileName)
{

    var file = new FileInfo(fileName);
    string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

    var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
    try
    {
        var scripts = script.Split(";");
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            foreach (var item in scripts)
            {
                command.Transaction = transaction;
                command.CommandText = item;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```